# How can I connect to ASP.NET Core's WebApplication.db database?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm experimenting with ASP.NET Core and have created a new Web Application (MVC) site with it:

```
git init CoreWebApp
cd CoreWebApp
dotnet new -t web
dotnet restore
```

After the code is bootstrapped I ran the initial EF migration

```
dotnet ef database update
```

At this point a database is generated at `./bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/WebApplication.db` and the site runs and allows users to be registered and login successfully.  I'd like to connect to that database via SSMS, LINQPad, or another standard SQL Client, but am having troubles.  The "open file" prompts typically look for a `.mdf` extension and complain about the `.db` file.

How do I connect to an ASP.NET Core, EF Generated WebApplication.db file from a SQL Client?

Comment: `.db`is SQLite and not SQL Server

Comment: ah, I'd thought (for no apparent reason) that was only on Linux hosts.  So I should be able to connect with any SQLite client by just pointing to the DB file, eh?

Comment: Yep. (damn 12 character limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dotnet new` command is created with portability in mind so it can also run on non-Windows systems. Since there is no SQLExpress for Linux and Mac, the template is created with SQLite as database.

So you need an SQLite client to open it.

Of course you're free to replace with any provider which supports EntityFramework Core, like SQLServer.

Just replace

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.1",
```

in your project.json with

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
```

and

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

with

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

in Startup.cs and finally the connection string in appsettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=WebApplication.db"
},
```

with the

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
}
```